# Is versionbit 28 on testnet something that can be disregarded?

Tags: bitcoind, testnet

My testnet node is displaying a value in the `getblockchaininfo` warnings field related to versionbit 28, which I see referenced in various threads [going back years](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/9080).

The angles I'm trying to address are:

- If I'm running the most recent version of core, is it still typical to see unknown rules once in a while? Should this situation be considered an unsupported softfork or something different?
- Where can I find out how to support newly activated rules i.e. what actions to take?
- Is this only some quirk because Bitcoin Classic forked on testnet ([see here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1471338.0))?

Here is some info from bitcoin-cli:

**--version**

```
    Bitcoin Core RPC client version v25.1
Copyright (C) 2009-2023 The Bitcoin Core developers

Please contribute if you find Bitcoin Core useful. Visit
<https://bitcoincore.org/> for further information about the software.
The source code is available from <https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin>.

This is experimental software.
Distributed under the MIT software license, see the accompanying file COPYING
or <https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT>
```

**-getinfo**

```
Chain: test
Blocks: 2537535
Headers: 2537535
Verification progress: 100.0000%
Difficulty: 85961336.19616741

Network: in 1, out 11, total 12
Version: 250100
```

**getblockchaininfo**

```
...
"warnings": "Unknown new rules activated (versionbit 28)"
```

Comment: Does [Impact: unknown rules (versionbit 2) have been activated](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/107734/5406) answer your question?

Comment: No, actually.. I'm running the most recent release of Bitcoin Core and versionbit 28 does not seem new, as I've linked a thread referring to it from years back. 
Any idea what versionbit 28 refers to or where I can learn about these feature/soft fork signals in general?