# Blockchain refund

Tags: wallet, fraud

I recently lost funds to a Bitcoin trader CryptoASX based in the UK (London) which turned out to be a fraudulent trader. Just today (Tuesday 19 October 2021) I received a phone call from an organisation calling themselves Blockchain Refund, also based in the UK.

Blockchain refund has is offering to refund my losses plus. To get my refund I need to set up an "Atomic Wallet" and provide them with a screenshot of 17% of the refund amount, before they will release the funds. They will send me the refund.

Does this sound legitimate?

Comment: This looks like a double scam. I wouldn't do what "Blockchain Refund" say.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a 'BTC Refund Department'?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/100096/is-there-a-btc-refund-department) -- What you describe is 100% a scam.  On this Q&A website you can see similar questions from many people scammed exactly this way.

Comment: see also https://www.fca.org.uk/news/warnings/blockchain-ltd-blockchain-refund-department-clone-fca-registered-emd-agent

Answer (score 2):

That is *definitely* another scam.

Answer (score 2):

People who fall for scams are a hot commodity and their details are being sold to other scammers because they are much more likely to fall for it again.

You should ask yourself why would a random organization call you out of nowhere and offer you free money, how does that make any sense?